# Receiving '403 Developer Inactive' when calling through Terminal, however getting data through browser

Tags: api

I am receiving the 403 Developer Inactive message when trying to use nytimes article search API in the terminal, but able to access the data in chrome. Leads me to believe my call is correct and my API key is active, but there's another problem.

In browser:

```
http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=new+york+times&page=2&sort=oldest&api-key=####
```

In terminal:

```
curl http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=new+york+times&page=2&sort=oldest&api-key=####
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up answering this one myself.

Duh, terminal encodes characters differently than my browser, and the ampersand needed to be surrounded with double quotes in order to pass correctly.

Hopefully this may help any other poor beginners out there.

Comment: In my case it was changing 'api_key' to 'api-key'